# WP7 - Isolated file creation date/time format?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, listbox

I was just wondering if there is a way that I can get the creation date and time of a file. To simplify things so far this is what I got:

```
 Dim Storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim directory As String = "./SafeLockPLUS/SavedAccounts/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = Storage.GetFileNames(directory)
    Dim dataSource As New List(Of SampleData)()
    For Each filename As String In filenames
        Dim ISF As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        Dim FS As IsolatedStorageFileStream = ISF.OpenFile("SafeLockPLUS/SavedAccounts/" & filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using SR As New StreamReader(FS)
            Dim Tme1 As String = Storage.GetLastWriteTime("/SafeLockPLUS/SavedAccounts/" & filename).DateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)
            Dim DATESS As String = SR.ReadLine
            Dim ReadName As String = SR.ReadLine
            Dim DATESSx2 As String = SR.ReadLine
            Dim Nte As String = SR.ReadLine
            dataSource.Add(New SampleData() With {.Name = filename, .Description = ReadName, .Tme = Tme1, .Notes1 = Nte})
        End Using
    Next
    SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = dataSource
```

So the time format of the file creation is like e.g. 3:22 p.m. 4:22 p.m. But the problem is that lets say i created the file on 12th, 11, 2013 at 2:34 p.m and i look at the file again on 14th, 11, 2013, the file creation date.time will show as 2:34 p.m even though it was created a while back. How can i do it so that it will show the time on the day it was created but if i check it sometime later e.g. 2 to 3 days later it will show something like 11/12 or Tue. Just like how when you go to the message list, it shows the time but sometime later it will show the date of it and not the time.

Comment: print out Description to see before "SavedAccountslst.ItemsSource = dataSource" to check the value.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that quick reply but what do you mean?

Comment: Didn't see you message for a day. Print out the value of SampleData.Description. and see value before binding.

Comment: Hey! uhh yea so after posting this i managed to get it working: http://puu.sh/5stpD.png but now the problem im facing is that lets say i created the file yesterday, and if i look at it today that time shows it as when i created even if the date is different. This is quite misleading. I was wondering if i can do it in a way that if i created the file yesterday and i look at it to day the date will show e.g. (file created: 11/11/13 looked at 14/11/13 it will shows as 11/11.